# change color of displayed double value in java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, sdk

I would like to change the color of my displayed value however it is a double and I am unable to use < operand to write an if conditional.
The displayed value is a BAC level so I cant rewrite the entire program to take int values even if I wanted to. If the BAC is less than 0.8 it the color should display green, if greater than 0.7 it should be red. HELP!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

    Button backHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goHome);
    TextView bloodAlcoholContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bloodAlcoholContent);


    Bundle f = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bundle m = getIntent().getExtras();
    final Double sendThisF = f.getDouble("actualBacF");
    final Double sendThisM = m.getDouble("actualBacM");

    if (m.containsKey("actualBacM")) {
        String displayBac = String.format("%.2f", sendThisM);

        //I would like to put if statement here but it is not allowed
        if (displayBac < 0.8) {

        }
    }

    else if (f.containsKey("actualBacF")) {
        String displayBac = String.format("%.2f", sendThisF);
        bloodAlcoholContent.setText(displayBac);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change your question title as it is misleading.  "Change color of displayed double value in Java" implies you are having trouble changing the  color.  That is not the case.

Comment: I am having trouble changing the color. The code works just fine without me wanting to edit the color

Comment: @7kevin No, you were having trouble writing an if statement to compare a number.  What you wanted to do with that if statement is irrelevant for your question.  The reason why this difference matters is that other people having problems comparing numbers won't find it, but those with actual problems changing colors will, and neither will be helped.

Comment: OK your absolutely right! Thanks for the correction and I will be sure to explain myself and/or set the title better. Have a great day!!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a String and a number.  That won't even compile.  Change `displayBac` to `sendThisM`, which is the actual numeric value of interest.

```
if (sendThisM < 0.8) {
}
```

While you are at it, you might want to give the variable a more descriptive name than `sendThisM`.

Comment: It does compile. The code works just fine without me wanting to change the color

Comment: Hey, your solution did cause the red line to disappear. Thank you sir!!!